# Prepend custom css to generated CSS files

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

here is my problem :

I am working with WordPress and I have simple buttons shortcode.

The user have the possibility to choose a color for each button they create and also a color when the button is hovered.

I got custom css `<style>` tag generated for each button, it works fine but there is only one problem, it creates a lot of `<style>` tag in the page and when using IE9 ( which has a limit of 31 ) the button style doesn't apply.

The css is generated with php with my shortcode function.

I am looking for a way to generate the css into a dynamic css file.
If all the `<style>` are put into a single css file it should works with IE but I don't know how I could do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it with jQuery:

```
function isIE() {
    return (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie ') != -1) || (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv[:]*11\./));
}

$(function() {
    if (isIE()) {
        //merging all the content in your generated styles
        var styles = $("style").text();
        //getting rid of the many unneeded styles
        $("style").remove();
        //Putting back all the styles into your document
        $("head").append("<style>" + styles + "</style>");
    }
});
```

The idea is to merge the styles into a single text, remove all the styles and then create a single style tag instead of them. You need this only for IE, so I have added a function with which you can check whether it is Internet Explorer and if so, then merge the styles.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to generate one custom style section in the head of your pages, assuming these are dynamically generated. You need to inlude your main CSS files before this section to be able to override values.

Answer (score 0):

if you like too, you can send all the custom css to a new file by using the 'fopen()':

```
function CreateCustomCSSFile(){
$file = fopen("wp-content/themes/your_theme/css/your_stylesheet_custom_file.css","w"); // change the target path as you like
$Color1 = '#eee'; // your custom color 1 - replace the Hex value with the custom field input
$Color2 = '#000'; // your custom color 2 - replace the Hex value with the custom field input
// getting the custom values into css
$TheCSSLayout = '
.someclass1
{
    background: ' . $Color1 . ';
}

.someclass2
{
    background: ' . $Color2 . '; 
}
';
fwrite($file, $TheCSSLayout); // writing to the file
fclose($file); // closing the file
}
CreateCustomCSSFile();
```

insert it into the function.php file and call the new file to the end of the css include files at the head so it will overwrite the default css settings.